# Environment variables for build not visible in Dockerfile

Tags: npm, docker-cloud

I've set an environment variable (NPM_TOKEN) for my repo in Docker Cloud to use when building my Dockerfile. However, the variable is always empty...

Tried both of these in Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo ${NPM_TOKEN}
```

and:

```
ARG NPM_TOKEN
RUN echo ${NPM_TOKEN}
```

Am I wrong in assuming that Docker Clouds environment variables for build does the same thing as --build-arg?

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: No... Ended up with the crappy solution of checking in .npmrc into my github repo.

Answer (score 0):

It took me along time, but you can use build hooks to set variables for automated builds!

https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/advanced/#build-hook-examples